# Vim color scheme for Latex

Tags: vim

I would like suggestions for a Vim color scheme for Latex. I love gruvbox for coding but it fails to highlight most Latex commands. Besides, maybe something different for typesetting is a good idea (perhaps something designed for a light background, but it's not mandatory). I've tried Solarized but find the contrast to low for both light and dark versions.